# SEM: aren't square of "disturbance" and "path coefficient" of manifest var supposed to add up to 1?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

Per [Norman and Streiner](http://prof.usb.ve/jjramirez/POSTGRADO/AFC/Art03%20Cap%2017%20Path%20Analysis%20y%20SEM.pdf), in a path diagram, for a manifest variable, square of "disturbance" and "path coefficient" are supposed to add up to 1.

So, how come in this image below from [this web page](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fnbeh.2016.00067/full), they are not adding up to 1?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. If estimates are given in standardized units, the path loading squared (which can then be regarded as percentage of variance explained here) and the residual variance should sum up to one.

I get .554+.668^2=1.000

Comment: I got it now. The variance = disturbance^2, and what's listed here are variances and not disturbances.