# Share of accounted variance by each predictors in SEM

Tags: variance, structural-equation-modeling, variance-decomposition

I have fitted a SEM model with 3 endogenous variables, 2 of them acting as mediators. I know that using lavaan it reports the r-squared for each endogenous variable. However, reading a paper it states "intelligence in childhood accounted for 23.2% and parental social class for 17.6% of the total variation in social attainment in mid-life (here main outcome)".

I was wondering how is it possible to compute/derive the share of accounted variance by each determinants. In the quote of the paper, for example, both intelligence and parental social class are two exogenous variables. How can I obtain this portion of explained variance? Is it the squared of the standardized total effect?

Thanks all

Comment: There's nothing special about variance accounted for - it's just the same as regression. And if your predictor variables are correlated, you can't determine which of them account for which proportion of variance.

Comment: It appears that the quote is from the introduction to a paper which is citing this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0160289605000656 . I don't have access to that, so I can't see what they actually did.

Comment: Yes, exactly...but then they did not explain how they compute the variance accounted for social class or childhood intelligence. As they allow for (residual) correlations as well in the SEM model, I was wondering how they compute it. However, I was reading that if the coefficients are standardized, their square can be interpreted as variance accounted for. Indeed, the residual variance of the variable + standardized path^2 need to sum up to 1 (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261608/sem-arent-square-of-disturbance-and-path-coefficient-of-manifest-var-suppo)

Comment: If you square the standardized paths, and sum them, you'll find that that can add up to more than 1. Clearly you can't account for more than 100% of the variance, so that's not right.

Comment: If the predictors are correlated, they share variance.

Comment: But in SEM you allow for residual correlation, meaning that a latent variable explains both unaccounted variance, no? If the link I attach you is correct, where the sum of residual and squared path is equal to 1, then it should be true that the squared standardized path should represent the accounted variance for that endogenous variable (LPS-4 in the example of the link to stackexchange)?

Comment: In that question, the endogenous variable (it makes no difference if it's latent or not) has only one predictor.

Comment: That's what confuse me, as also in another paper (Von Stumm et al, 2009) they state "Educational qualifications were found to account for 10.9% of the total variance in social status attainment and partly mediated the effects of parental social class, intelligence, childhood disturbance and locus of control" which is the square of the direct path from education to outcome variable, but there are more than one predictor....